# Extracting specific data from outlook emails and store it into excel file

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Message Body format:

```
> Hi All,
> 
> 
> Redwood.Harel.Harley.Miscare.Find failed. Below is the detailed report
> 
> **************************************************************************************  Server Name : freedyishere1234 
> 
> 
> Service Name : SantaIsRed
> 
> 
> Transaction Id : 32k23k23k-234jbk23b4k-32j4k23b-23231q
> 
> 
> Universal Id : 8979870
> 
> 
> Employee Id : 123123321
> 
> 
> Service Status : Failed 
> 
> 
> Error Details : The family’s excitement over going to Disneyland was
> crazier than she anticipated. EmployeeId=123123321
>  
>                 
> ************************************************************************************** 
> 
> This is a system generated message. Do not reply to this message. 
> 
> Thank you,  Cranberry Team
```

I want to write a VBA which runs everyday(or manually as well) at specific time and date (past, present,future). My script should extract `EmployeeId` and `Error Details` from the body and save it into an excel file which has to be maintained everyday.

```
Column A = EmployeeId

Column B = Error
```

of excel.

Everyday data should be seperated from last date by just 1 or 2 empty rows in excel.

My code:

```
Sub ExtractEmailData()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objTS As Object
    Dim strText As String
    Dim EmployeeID As String
    Dim Error As String
    Dim OlInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    
    'Set Outlook application object
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    
    'Set Outlook namespace
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    'olFolderI is Inbox folder
    Set olFolderI = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'Get the parent folder of the Inbox folder
    Dim olParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olParentFolder = olFolderI.Parent

    ' Loop through all the subfolders of the parent folder
    For Each subfolder In olParentFolder.Folders
        'set olFolder as TARGET123
        If subfolder.Name = "TARGET123" Then
            Set olFolder = subfolder
        End If
    Next
    
    
    'Path of the Windows desktop folder
    DesktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
    
    'Loop through emails in TARGET123 folder
    For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
    
    'Extract EmployeeID and Error from email body
    EmployeeID = ExtractData(olMail.Body, "Employee Id:\s*(\d+)")
    Error = ExtractData(olMail.Body, "Error Details:\s*(.+)")
    
    'Create string to write to file
    strText = EmployeeID + "," + Error + vbNewLine
    
    'Set file name and location
    strFile = DesktopPath + Format(Now(), "dd-MMM-yyyy") + ".csv"
    
    'Check if file already exists
    If Len(Dir(strFile)) = 0 Then
    
    'Create new file and write headers
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTS = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFile, True)
    objTS.WriteLine "EmployeeID,Error"
    objTS.Close
    
    Else
    
    'Open file and append data
    Open strFile For Append As #1
    Print #1, strText
    Close #1
    
    End If
    
    Next olMail
    
    'Clean up
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objTS = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
    End Sub
    
    'Function to extract data using regular expressions
    Public Function ExtractData(strText As String, strPattern As String) As String
    
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.Pattern = strPattern
    objRegEx.Global = True
    
    If objRegEx.Test(strText) Then
        ExtractData = objRegEx.Execute(strText)(0).SubMatches(0)
    Else
        ExtractData = ""
    End If
    
    Set objRegEx = Nothing
    
    End Function
    
    
    'Application.OnTime TimeValue("20:00:00"), "ExtractEmailData"
    
    
    'You can also specify a specific date and time for the macro to run using the Application.OnTime method, for example:
    Public Sub ScheduleMacro()
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "ExtractEmailData"
    End Sub
    
    ScheduleMacro


End Sub
```

But this code just creates a new file everyday(which is also fine) and the columns created are also fine but there is not data being extracted from emails and populated into the excel file.

Comment: You need to use the debugger to step through your code and understand what is happening. Perhaps it doesn't find the emails that it should. Perhaps it doesn't find the text in them. Perhaps it doesn't write properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following code doesn't add the retrieved in Outlook data to the Excel file:

```
  'Open file and append data
    Open strFile For Append As #1
    Print #1, strText
    Close #1
```

Try to set a break point and go through each line of code under the debugger attached.

Also keep in mind that Outlook folders may contain different kind of items - emails, appointments, documents, notes and etc. So, it makes sense to make sure that you deal with mail items before accessing its properties. For example, not all properties may be available. In the code you iterate over items assuming they are all mail items:

```
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
 'Loop through emails in TARGET123 folder
    For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
```

Instead, I'd suggest declaring the item as object and check the `MessageClass` before casting to the `MailItem` class to make sure you deal with a true mail item.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I am a total newbie with VBA. I am still trying to understand what you said in your response. Plus, I am also trying to use CHAT GPT to solve this issue. Hopefully that might also work.

Comment: Also, I have created a rule to make the outlook emails coming into the inbox that I want to extract data from; go to a folder named TARGET123. So, this folder has only emails that I need to parse. So, my only concern is why I cannot extract the data.

DEBUG PRINT is what I am not able to use here. I tried using it once but it doesn't show me what I want to see. That's the problem. Otherwise, I could have solved this problem.

Comment: Run your code under the debugger attached and go through each line of code checking intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

Labels have to be exactly as in the mail.

```vb
'Extract EmployeeID and Error details from email body
'EmployeeID = ExtractData(olMail.Body, "Employee Id:\s*(\d+)")
'Error = ExtractData(olMail.Body, "Error Details:\s*(.+)")
EmployeeID = ExtractData(objMail.Body, "Employee Id :\s*(\d+)")
strError = ExtractData(objMail.Body, "Error Details :\s*(.+)")
```